# Is there a better way to bind to lazy loaded values?

Tags: angular

Just wondering if anyone knows of a better way than:

```
<config-input title="IP Address" [(model)]="data && data.StaticIP" type="ip" subText="{{(data && ('Current: ' + data.CurrIP)) || 'Current: '}}"></config-input>
<config-input title="Netmask" [(model)]="data && data.StaticNetmask" type="ip" subText="{{(data && ('Current: ' + data.CurrNetmask)) || 'Current: '}}"></config-input>
<config-input title="Gateway" [(model)]="data && data.StaticGateway" type="ip" subText="{{(data && ('Current: ' + data.CurrGateway)) || 'Current: '}}"></config-input>
<config-input title="Primary DNS" [(model)]="data && data.StaticDNS1" type="ip" subText="{{(data && ('Current: ' + data.CurrDNS1)) || 'Current: '}}"></config-input>
<config-input title="Secondary DNS" [(model)]="data && data.StaticDNS2" type="ip" subText="{{(data && ('Current: ' + data.CurrDNS2)) || 'Current: '}}"></config-input>
```

In angular 1, it had the undefined protection built in. It's ugly and annoying to constantly have to do the check on values. I get why its there, just wondering if there's something more elegant.

Comment: Loaded lazily from where? If you get it from an observable you can use `| async` to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Angular [safe navigation operator ( ?. )](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator), also known as 'Elvis' operator. Usage:

```
{{data?.CurrIP}}
```

It prevents a view render failure if there are `null` or `undefined` values in property path.